# Что означает фраза: "бабушка надвое сказала"?

Tags: этимология

Что означает фраза: "бабушка надвое сказала"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это упрощение поговорки, означающее неоднозначность чего-то (напр., в ответ на утверждение, вместо прямого возражения "не так ясно, чем закончится").
Бабушка гадала, да надвое сказала: то ли дождь, то ли снег; то ли будет, то ли нет.